# Magento 2.1: Illegal string offset 'price_qty'. After importing tier price cvs file, I can't edit products in backend anymore

Tags: php, magento

By using Magento 2.1.3 after importing tier price cvs file, I can't edit products in backend anymore.The error in backend is

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'price_qty' in  vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Tierprice.php on line 74

In the report, I found 25 reports, the newest is

> `#`1/vendor/magento/modulecatalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Validate.php(108): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Validate->checkUniqueOption(Object(Magento\Framew
>   ork\DataObject), Array).

Can someone help me to resolve this problem pls. Thank you so much.
Tierprice.php

namespace Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend;

class Tierprice extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\GroupPrice\AbstractGroupPrice
{

```
protected $_productAttributeBackendTierprice;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $catalogData
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type $catalogProductType
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupManagementInterface $groupManagement
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Backend\Tierprice $productAttributeTierprice
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $catalogData,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config,
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type $catalogProductType,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupManagementInterface $groupManagement,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Backend\Tierprice $productAttributeTierprice
) {
    $this->_productAttributeBackendTierprice = $productAttributeTierprice;
    parent::__construct(
        $currencyFactory,
        $storeManager,
        $catalogData,
        $config,
        $localeFormat,
        $catalogProductType,
        $groupManagement
    );
}


protected function _getResource()
{
    return $this->_productAttributeBackendTierprice;
}


protected function _getAdditionalUniqueFields($objectArray)
{
    $uniqueFields = parent::_getAdditionalUniqueFields($objectArray);
    $uniqueFields['qty'] = $objectArray['price_qty'] * 1;
    return $uniqueFields;
}


protected function _getDuplicateErrorMessage()
{
    return __('We found a duplicate website, tier price, customer group and quantity.');
}

 protected function _isPriceFixed($priceObject)
{
    return $priceObject->isTierPriceFixed();
}

public function isScalar()
{
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post your code that's causing the error?

Comment: protected function _getAdditionalUniqueFields($objectArray)
 tierprice.php on row 74:   {
        $uniqueFields = parent::_getAdditionalUniqueFields($objectArray);
        $uniqueFields['qty'] = $objectArray['price_qty'] * 1;
        return $uniqueFields;
    }

Comment: I mean enough of it to debug, and you can edit the question body to add it.

Comment: Can someone help me please, I cant edit  anything from my old products. Please please please

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same issue with tier pricing while product save. I just checked if $objectArray['price_qty'] isset before using it and that resolved my issue temporarily. However, its a temporary fix but works for now

Just replace below function

```
protected function _getAdditionalUniqueFields($objectArray)
{
    $uniqueFields = parent::_getAdditionalUniqueFields($objectArray);
    $uniqueFields['qty'] = $objectArray['price_qty'] * 1;

    return $uniqueFields;
}
```

with

```
protected function _getAdditionalUniqueFields($objectArray)
{
    $uniqueFields = parent::_getAdditionalUniqueFields($objectArray);
    if(isset($objectArray['price_qty'])){
        $uniqueFields['qty'] = $objectArray['price_qty'] * 1;
    }
    return $uniqueFields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in 2.2.5 EE

after following these steps I managed to get this fixed.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8426

1. Backup your database (optional)
2. Locate your "tier_price" attribute ID (Stores -> Attributes -> Product -> Search for "tier_price") or from eav_attribute table
3. Search catalog_product_entity_decimal, catalog_product_entity_int, catalog_product_entity_text, and catalog_product_entity_varchar for any records with the attribute_id of your tier_price attribute.
4. Delete these rows
5. Try saving product again.